# PHP how to remove last separator?

Tags: php, separator

I have tried a tons of variations, but I can't find the solution. Previously the output was like this:

1. word a
2. word b
3. word c
   etc

I have changed some parts of code and now output is:

word a | word b | word c |

How to remove last separator?

The code is:

```
<div id="right">

        <div id="synonyms">
        <?

        $separator = '<span class="pipe">|</span>';

        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT word, id_word FROM words WHERE word LIKE '$word' ORDER BY word ASC LIMIT 100");
        echo mysql_error();

        while ($row=mysql_fetch_row($sql))
            {
                $word_synonym = $row[0];        
                $id_word_synonym = $row[1];                 


                        $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT synonym, id_synonym FROM synonyms WHERE id_word = '$id_word_synonym' ORDER BY synonym ASC");
                        echo mysql_error();
                        $num_results =mysql_num_rows($sql2);

                        while ($row=mysql_fetch_row($sql2))
                            {
                            $synonym = $row[0];
                            $id_synonym = $row[1];

                            $synonym2 = str_replace(" ", "+", $synonym);

                            echo "".$separator."<a href=".$site_url."/?word=".$synonym2.">".$synonym."</a>  ";



                            }

            }
        ?>
        </div>
```

I tried to add `$separator = substr($separator, -1, 0);` and a lot of other suggestions, but without result.

Comment: Unrelated, but you can replace `echo "".$separator."<a href=".$site_url."/?word=".$synonym2.">".$synonym."</a>  ";` with `echo "$separator<a href=$site_url/?word=$synonym2>$synonym</a>";`

Answer (score 4):

My preference when doing something like this is to build an array of the strings, then use [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) when outputting the final string. This is particularly useful because then I can do other things like merge groups, filter them, etc.

Comment: I do this so much it should be illegal

Comment: I like this method, too. Very clean. Something like `implode($separator,$values)`.

Comment: i do this too, more often then i care to admit

Answer (score 0):

This was posted before and removed, but I think it's worth including as an optional method. Although I prefer Kolink's method, I've used this, too:

Use an iterator ($i) to identify the first (or last) item.

```
$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($sql2)) {
  $i++;
  $synonym = $row[0];
  $id_synonym = $row[1];
  $synonym2 = str_replace(" ", "+", $synonym);
  echo ($i>1?$separator:"").'<a href="$site_url/?word=$synonym2">$synonym</a>';
}
```

Not part of this answer, but here's an example of Kolink's (arguably superior) method:

```
$links=array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($sql2)) {
  $synonym = $row[0];
  $id_synonym = $row[1];
  $synonym2 = str_replace(" ", "+", $synonym);
  $links[]='<a href="$site_url/?word=$synonym2">$synonym</a>';
}

if (!empty($links)) {
  echo implode($separator,$links);
}
```